# How to make simple multiple nominals using PHP?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a code like this

```
<?php if 
($trx->de_amount2 == '10000' ||$trx->de_amount2 == '15000'||$trx->de_amount2 == '20000'||$trx->de_amount2 == '25000'||$trx->de_amount2 == '30000' ):?>
 ok
<?php else:?>
no
<?php endif;?>
```

I want to make multiples of numbers from 5000 to 1 million with a simple code not like this

```
$trx->de_amount2 == '10000' ||$trx->de_amount2 == '15000'
```

How do I do that?

Comment: you can use Modulo (%)

Comment: `if ($trx->de_amount2 >= 5000 && $trx->de_amount2 <= 1000000 && $trx->de_amount2 % 5000 == 0)`

Comment: this working.. thank :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use in_array with range.

```
if(in_array($trx->de_amount2, range(5000, 1000000, 5000))){
    echo "ok";
}else{
    echo "not ok";
}
```

Range creates an array with all values between 5000 and 1000000 with 5000 increments.
In_array checks if the value is in the array (range).

Comment: this working too... this is simple ... thanks